# Error when trying to get a list of folders containing images

Tags: java, android, list, image

Good morning, I'm making an application that needs its own image gallery, so to get a list of folders that contain files with the formats ".png", ".jpeg", ".jpg" and ".webp" I created this one code below:

```
public static void loadPaths(String path, LoadImageListener listener, Handler handler) {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(listener::onStart);

                ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<String> usedPaths = new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<GalleryObject> galleryObjects = new ArrayList<>();

                paths.add(path);
                for(int i = 0; i < paths.size(); i++) {
                    String filePath = paths.get(i);
                    ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<>(getListDir(filePath));

                    if(!files.contains(filePath + "/.nomedia"))
                        for(String stringFiles : files) {
                            File file = new File(stringFiles);

                            if(!file.getName().startsWith("."))
                                if(file.isDirectory()) paths.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
                                else if(checkFormat(file.getName()) && !usedPaths.contains(filePath)) {
                                    GalleryObject galleryObject = new GalleryObject(file.getAbsolutePath(), true);
                                    galleryObjects.add(galleryObject);
                                    usedPaths.add(filePath);
                                }
                        }
                }

                handler.post(()-> listener.onFinish(galleryObjects));
            }
        }.start();
    }

public static boolean checkFormat(String file) {
        if(file.endsWith(".png")) return true;
        if(file.endsWith(".jpg")) return true;
        if(file.endsWith(".jpeg")) return true;
        return file.endsWith(".webp");
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getListDir(String path) {
        ArrayList<String> listFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        File[] files = new File(path).listFiles();
        assert files != null;
        for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) listFiles.add(files.clone()[i].getAbsolutePath());
        return listFiles;
    }
```

Most of the time it works normally but every now and then it returns this error:

```
Process: com.petouch, PID: 31060
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified message queue synchronization  barrier token has not been posted or has already been removed.
        at android.os.MessageQueue.removeSyncBarrier(MessageQueue.java:515)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1471)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7266)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1004)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:816)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:751)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:990)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6694)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I noticed that this error only happens when I let use a thread or an async task in the loadPaths method but I couldn't find any way to solve the problem.

Full code without listener

```
                new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
                        ArrayList<String> usedPaths = new ArrayList<>();
                        ArrayList<GalleryObject> galleryObjects = new ArrayList<>();

                        paths.add("/storage/emulated/0/");
                        for(int i = 0; i < paths.size(); i++) {
                            String filePath = paths.get(i);
                            ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<>(FileUtil.getListDir(filePath));

                            if(!files.contains(filePath + "/.nomedia"))
                                for(String stringFiles : files) {
                                    File file = new File(stringFiles);

                                    if(!file.getName().startsWith("."))
                                        if(file.isDirectory()) paths.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
                                        else if(FileUtil.checkFormat(file.getName()) && !usedPaths.contains(filePath)) {
                                            GalleryObject galleryObject = new GalleryObject(file.getAbsolutePath(), true);
                                            galleryObjects.add(galleryObject);
                                            usedPaths.add(filePath);
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                        
                        handler.post(()-> {
                            GalleryActivity.galleryObjects.clear();
                            GalleryActivity.galleryObjects.addAll(galleryObjects);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, GalleryActivity.class);
                            toScreen(intent);
                        });

                    }
                }.start();
```

Comment: Please show with wich path you call loadPaths().

Comment: If you remove that listener and handler stuff, do you have the same error? If not then the subject of your post is not to the point.

Comment: I removed the listener and the error continues, the path I put in the loadPath was /storage/emulated/0/

Comment: Then show your new code.

Comment: I put the complete code without the listener in the question

Comment: Remove the handler too as otherwise you cannot say: `Error when trying to get a list of folders`. Find out which statement gives the error.

Comment: Ok, I will go deleting one thing at a time until I find where exactly the error is occurring

Comment: Sorry, I did several tests with my code and realized the error was originating from another part of my code where I displayed a load view I removed this and tested the old code 30 times none of which did the error occur, but thanks so much for your help friend